# Breeze hierarchical class error "Collection navigation properties may NOT be set."

Tags: inheritance, breeze

I have installed the last version of Breeze 1.3.2 for Inheritance support.
I have a hierarchical class with the association bidirectional:

```
public abstract class HClass
{        
    public HClass()
    {
        Children = new List<HClass>();
    }
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ParentId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<HClass> Children { get; set; }
    public virtual HClass Parent { get; set; }
}
```

I have other classes with Inheritance:

```
public class AClass : HClass
{
    public string Observation { get; set; }
}

public class BClass : HClass
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
}
```

The DbContext in the server:

```
public DbSet<AClass> Projects { get; set; }
public DbSet<BClass> OtherProjects { get; set; }
```

The server side controller methods:

```
[HttpGet]
    public ICollection<AClass> Projects()
    {
        ICollection<AClass> projects = new List<AClass>();
        AClass pro1 = new AClass(); AClass pro2 = new AClass(); AClass pro3 = new AClass(); AClass pro4 = new AClass();
        pro1.Id = 1;
        pro1.Name = "Project 1";
        pro1.Observation = "Main";
        pro2.Id = 2;
        pro2.Name = "Project 2";
        pro2.Observation = "Main";
        pro3.Id = 3;
        pro3.Name = "Sub Project 3";
        pro3.ParentId = 1;
        pro3.Parent = pro1;
        pro4.Id = 4;
        pro4.Name = "Sub Project 4";
        pro4.ParentId = 1;
        pro4.Parent = pro1;
        pro1.Children.Add(pro3);
        pro1.Children.Add(pro4);
        projects.Add(pro1);
        projects.Add(pro2);
        return projects;
    }
```

**The each item in "projects" had set "Parent" and "Children" items and method Projects return the hierarchical composition.**

But I have the next error `Collection navigation properties may NOT be set.`. When I was querying:

```
return entityQuery.from('Projects')
            .using(manager).execute()
            .then(success)
            .fail(queryFailed);
```

The error is in `breeze.debug.js`:

```
function updateRelatedEntity(relatedEntity, targetEntity, navigationProperty) {
    if (!relatedEntity) return;
    var propName = navigationProperty.name;
    var currentRelatedEntity = targetEntity.getProperty(propName);
    // check if the related entity is already hooked up
    if (currentRelatedEntity !== relatedEntity) {
        // if not hook up both directions.
        targetEntity.setProperty(propName, relatedEntity); //Error here
        var inverseProperty = navigationProperty.inverse;
        if (!inverseProperty) return;
        if (inverseProperty.isScalar) {
            relatedEntity.setProperty(inverseProperty.name, targetEntity);
        } else {
            var collection = relatedEntity.getProperty(inverseProperty.name);
            collection.push(targetEntity);
        }
    }
}
```

When I use `HClass`, breeze work perfectly, but the error appears when I use `AClass` or `BClass` with Inheritance.

I have updated to Breeze 1.3.3 but error persists

Please, help me with this error, any suggestion will be welcome.

Comment: When do you get this error? When you are querying or when you are trying to add entities on the client?  A little more detail would be great.

Comment: Thanks for your time and interest. The error occurred when I was querying.

Comment: Your query is for "Projects"? Are you saying that when "Projects" returns "HClass" it works but that when it returns "AClass" it fails? and.. can you show the server side controller method as well?

Comment: Yes, when I use HClass it works, but when I use AClass in dbContext and Controller it fails. I edited question and add some information from server.

Comment: We're looking into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We haven't been able to repro your error, so could you please email a "small" test case that shows the error to breeze.ideablade.com ( with Attn: Jay Traband somewhere in the email). The latest DocCode sample in the Breeze zips has an "Inheritance.sdf" database and an InheritanceController class that is very similar to yours, if you need a place to start.

Comment: Thanks for your interest, I sent a email to breeze@ideablade.com with subject: "Attn: Jay Traband : Please help me with: Breeze hierarchical class error."

Comment: I review the latest DocCode, and the only diference is in server side controller methods, for example my method "Projects" return collection of "AClass" but each item of projects had set the "Parent" and "Children" (because I need that).